# Can't find submit button name in req.body ( express, jade )

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I just study `node.js` in my interest.
I have an issue in my `node.js` source with `jade`.

There are 2 problems

1. When I clicked the 'save' button, I can't find 'save' in `req.body`
2. After I clicked the button, I got a message

   `throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');`

**Jade source**

```
doctype html
    html
      head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        title My Memo
      body
    h1 My Memo
    artcle
      form(method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data', action='/process/registerMemo')
        p
          label Author
          input(type='text', name='userName')
        p
          label Date
          input(type='date', name='writeDate')
        p
          label Description
          textarea(row='5', clos='40', name='usersNotes')
        p
          label Picture
          input(type='file', name='imgfile')
        p
          input(type='submit', value='save', name='save')
          input(type='submit', value='close', name='close')
```

**JSP source**

```
app.post('/process/registerMemo', function(req, res) {
    console.log('/process/registerMemo called');
    if (req.body.save)
        console.log('save button touched');
    else
        console.log('exit button touched');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.end("update failed");
        }

        var userName = req.body.userName;
        var writeDate = req.body.writeDate;
        var userNotes = req.body.usersNotes;
        console.log(req.body.userName);
        console.log(req.body.writeDate);
        console.log(req.body.usersNotes);
        console.log(req.body);
        if (req.body.save) {
            console.log('save button touched')            
            // var fileCount = files.length;
            // for( var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
            //   var savedFileName = files[i].filename;
            // }
            fs.writeFile('data/' + userName + '_' + Date.now(),
              userName + '/' + writeDate + '/' + userNotes, function(err) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
                  }
                  console.log('/public/myMemoResult should be called')
                  res.redirect('/public/registerMemo');
              })
        } else {
            // close button call
            console.log('close button touched')
            res.redirect('/public/myMemoResult');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: To parse the body of a request, you may need something like `body-parser`. Not very sure, but you need to check it.

Comment: And you already callled `res.end("update failed")`. Just like the error message said, once you called `res.end`, you can send no more. Probably you need a `return` after that line.

Comment: ok, thx a lot. i will check it~~